# How do you pass a function as an argument into the transform() function?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, iterator

I am trying to create a program that uses transform() to determine the size of strings in a vector and then put the results into a separate vector.

I do not fully understand how to pass a function into transform() and I am getting an error, any help would be much appreciated!

My code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

 // returns the size of a string
int stringLength(string str)
{
    return str.size();
}

int main()
{
          
    auto words = vector<string>{"This", "is", "a", "short", "sentence"};
    
    // vector to store number of characters in each string from 'words'
    auto result = vector<int>{};

    transform( words.begin(), words.end(), result.begin(), stringLength );

    for(auto answer : result)
    cout << answer << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

### Expected Output

4 2 1 5 8

### Actual Output

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you're passing a function to `transform`. The issue is your `result` vector is empty, so you invoke undefined behavior when you iterate from `result.begin()`. You need to do:

```
std::transform(words.begin(), words.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(result), stringLength);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/89fMdh).

You can also iterate from `result.begin()` in this case because you know exactly how many elements are going to be needed. All you need to do is allocate enough space at the beginning:

```
auto result = vector<int>(words.size());
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sr5Eox).

Answer (score 2):

You must allocate buffer to be written via `transform()` before calling that.

In this case, you should use

```
auto result = vector<int>(words.size());
```

instead of

```
auto result = vector<int>{};
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) as well.